# Akka singleton actor doesnt receive messages

Tags: java, unit-testing, akka, actor

I've tried to present here as simple variation as possible of the issue..
I wrote a unit test, that as a side effect of the code, a singleton actor is created. Inside his preStart method, he creates other singleton actors by calling the **startJobCoordinator** method.

```
private boolean startJobCoordinator(JobConfiguration jobConfiguration) throws InterruptedException  {
    ActorRef jobRef = createSingletonActor(Props.create(JobCoordinator.class, jobConfiguration.getId()), jobConfiguration.getId());
    jobRef.tell("DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD", self());
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
    return true;
}

private ActorRef createSingletonActor(Props props, final String name) {
    final ClusterSingletonManagerSettings settings = ClusterSingletonManagerSettings.create(getContext().system());
    getContext().actorOf(ClusterSingletonManager.props(props, PoisonPill.getInstance(), settings), name);

    ClusterSingletonProxySettings proxySettings = ClusterSingletonProxySettings.create(getContext().system());
    return getContext().actorOf(ClusterSingletonProxy.props("/user" + name, proxySettings), name + "Proxy");
}
```

Now, inside the JobCoordinator singleton actor which is of type AbstractActor, I've written a **receive** method as follows:

```
match(String.class, System.err::println).build();
```

In the unit test, the "*DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD*" message wasnt received (and wasnt printed).

When the same code is being run as part of running the whole system, the JobCoordinator actor gets the message.
When I create the JobCoordinator as a regular actor instead of a singleton, he gets the message (even as part of a unit test).

I'm really clueless.. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: It will be useful if you show us the code for `JobCoordinator`, `ClusterSingletonManager`, `ClusterSingletonProxy` and `ClusterSingletonManagerSettings`. There are a number of layers of complexity in your design which make it hard to follow so it's probably worth reviewing.

Comment: ClusterSingletonProxy, ClusterSingletonManager and ClusterSingletonManagerSettings are all akka classes

Only job coordinator isn't, and I'm not sure I'm allowed to publish the code here.
The problem somehow disappeared, I'm not sure how.. I'll update if I'll come up with the answer, for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I used JMock in the test to mock JobCoordinator (used by a different test, but the annotation influenced this test as well).